# how to insert row in first line of text file?

Tags: c#

I have a test file that contains

```
1,2,3
2,3,4
5,6,7
```

I want to insert this into the first line: `A,B,C`

So that I get:

```
A,B,C
1,2,3
2,3,4
5,6,7
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Similar to the previous answers, but this illustrates how to do what you want to do while minimizing memory consumption. There is no way around reading through the entire file you want to modify, even if you open it in a read/write stream, because you can't "insert" data.

```
static void WriteABC(string filename)
{
    string tempfile = Path.GetTempFileName();
    using (var writer = new StreamWriter(tempfile))
    using (var reader = new StreamReader(filename))
    {
        writer.WriteLine("A,B,C");
        while (!reader.EndOfStream)
            writer.WriteLine(reader.ReadLine());
    }
    File.Copy(tempfile, filename, true);
}
```

Comment: Awesome, but I wonder, should we be ´File.Delete(tempfile)´ at the end or is it better to leave it for the system to clean up?

Comment: Yes, it's better to delete the file, why leave something we don't need anymore?

Comment: better yet use File.Move

Answer (score 4):

I think this answer is easier and faster:

```
public static void WriteToFile(string Path, string Text)
{
    string content = File.ReadAllText(Path);
    content = Text + "\n" + content;      
    File.WriteAllText(Path, content);
}
```

Then you can call it:

```
WriteToFile("yourfilepath", "A,B,C");
```

Comment: It is good for smaller files, but for for larger files you can run into memory issues.

Comment: We need to specify the encoding, otherwise, it will read a file well, but then write it with a different encoding.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a link that explains how to use the TextReader (StreamReader) and TextWriter (StreamWriter) classes in C#.

http://www.csharpfriends.com/Articles/getArticle.aspx?articleID=132

Though this is specific to C#, the approach could be relatively the same across many languages.

(Note: There are several ways to do this, this is just one idea that comes quickly to mind.)

Essentially, you could read in the contents of your text file into a string, find the beginning of that string, write your information (A,B,C with your carriage returns or line feeds) and then write that information back out into the text file overwriting the original contents and save.

Comment: What if your file is 10MB, or 100MB? Would you read that all into a string (in memory)? That's not very efficient.

Comment: +1 - The temptation is to believe that you can "insert" a line at the beginning of the file, leaving the rest intact.  It doesn't work that way so you are right to point it out.

Comment: Joshua did mention both the StreamReader and StreamWriter.  If Gold used both, then it could be done line by line, which is again, not very efficient, but it would work without worry of an OutOfMemoryException.

Comment: The answer says: 'you could read in the contents of your text file into a string'. This is simply a bad idea unless you know for certain that the file will never be larger then some size (depending on your environment).

Answer (score 2):

Late to the party...

Good question. You can use this code:

```
static void WriteABC2(string filename)
{
    string tempfile = Path.GetTempFileName();
    using (var writer = new FileStream(tempfile, FileMode.Create))
    using (var reader = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Open))
    {
        var stringBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("A,B,C" + Environment.NewLine);
        writer.Write(stringBytes, 0, stringBytes.Length);

        reader.CopyTo(writer);
    }
    File.Copy(tempfile, filename, true);
    File.Delete(tempfile);
}
```

This code is based on the excellent [Jake](https://stackoverflow.com/users/258809/jake) answer, but I use `FileStream` instead of `StreamWriter` and `StreamReader`. There are big performance improvements (even 4X faster from my test) using `FileStream` when big files are processed. Just to be a little clear, I made some test and I reported the results below.

### How I made tests

I created 7 files. Each file contains 10^X lines and its name is `file<line count>.txt`. So the list of the files is:

```
| File name       | Line count | File size |
|-----------------|------------|-----------|
| file1.txt       |          1 | 66 byte   |
| file10.txt      |         10 | 678 byte  |
| file100.txt     |        100 | 6,72 KB   |
| file1000.txt    |       1000 | 68,2 KB   |
| file10000.txt   |      10000 | 692 KB    |
| file100000.txt  |     100000 | 6,85 MB   |
| file1000000.txt |    1000000 | 69,5 MB   |
```

Each line of each file is composed as follows:

```
<line index starting from 0> - abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789
```

For example, the first two lines of `file10.txt` are:

```
0 - abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789
1 - abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789
```

I used the below code to make tests and to get the function execution duration:

```
var stopwatch = new Stopwatch();

long abcTotalDuration = 0;
long abc2TotalDuration = 0;

string fileInput = "file1.txt";
string outputFolder = "output";

for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
    string filename1 = Path.Combine(outputFolder, Guid.NewGuid().ToString());
    string filename2 = Path.Combine(outputFolder, Guid.NewGuid().ToString());

    stopwatch.Restart();
    WriteABC(fileInput, filename1);
    stopwatch.Stop();
    abcTotalDuration += stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds;

    stopwatch.Restart();
    WriteABC2(fileInput, filename2);
    stopwatch.Stop();
    abc2TotalDuration += stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds;

    File.Delete(filename1);
    File.Delete(filename2);
}

Console.WriteLine("ABC : " + abcTotalDuration.ToString());
Console.WriteLine("ABC2: " + abc2TotalDuration.ToString());

// Just to wake me up :-)
Console.Beep(800, 1000);

Console.ReadKey();
```

The test consists of prepending `A,B,C(new line)` for each specified file. The result is saved in separate file (only for test).

I launched the code 5 times for each input file (specified in `fileInput` variable). `WriteABC` and `WriteABC2` functions are executed 100 times each every time I launch the code.

Here are the results (all in ms):

**Processing *file1.txt***

```
      | ABC | ABC2 |
      |-----|------|
      | 285 |  305 |
      | 356 |  352 |
      | 435 |  371 |
      | 355 |  313 |
      | 362 |  372 |
|-----|-----|------|
  AVG | 359 |  343 |
|-----|-----|------|
```

---

**Processing *file10.txt***

```
      | ABC | ABC2 |
      |-----|------|
      | 256 |  251 |
      | 273 |  323 |
      | 355 |  347 |
      | 350 |  314 |
      | 315 |  286 |
|-----|-----|------|
  AVG | 310 |  304 |
|-----|-----|------|
```

---

**Processing *file100.txt***

```
      | ABC | ABC2 |
      |-----|------|
      | 247 |  253 |
      | 239 |  246 |
      | 357 |  353 |
      | 387 |  334 |
      | 333 |  329 |
|-----|-----|------|
  AVG | 313 |  303 |
|-----|-----|------|
```

---

**Processing *file1000.txt***

```
      | ABC  | ABC2  |
      |------|-------|
      |  977 |   924 |
      |  784 |   738 |
      |  818 |   764 |
      | 1142 |  1101 |
      |  975 |   903 |
|-----|------|-------|
  AVG |  939 |   886 |
|-----|------|-------|
```

---

**Processing *file10000.txt***

```
      | ABC  | ABC2  |
      |------|-------|
      | 1150 |   748 |
      | 1147 |   811 |
      | 1069 |   654 |
      | 1181 |   799 |
      | 1234 |   805 |
|-----|------|-------|
  AVG | 1156 |   763 |
|-----|------|-------|
```

---

**Processing *file100000.txt***

```
      | ABC  | ABC2  |
      |------|-------|
      | 5485 |  1769 |
      | 5268 |  1528 |
      | 5296 |  1555 |
      | 5308 |  1529 |
      | 5289 |  1553 |
|-----|------|-------|
  AVG | 5329 |  1587 |
|-----|------|-------|
```

---

**Processing *file1000000.txt***

```
      | ABC   | ABC2   |
      |-------|--------|
      | 49034 |  12633 |
      | 52116 |  12484 |
      | 51643 |  12109 |
      | 52022 |  12359 |
      | 53145 |  12716 |
|-----|-------|--------|
  AVG | 51592 |  12460 |
|-----|-------|--------|
```

The difference becomes remarkable from `file10000.txt`.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot 'insert' anything in a Text file.

You will have to

- copy the contents
- inert extra data at the right time
- close the files
- delete the original and rename the new one to the old name

Comment: @rwwilden: You seem to be advocating the impossible. Have you tested this theory? See the comments to your answer.

Comment: @rwwilden: Actually that **IS** true, you can only "insert at the end" i.e. append, anything else is overwriting part of the existing file.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, my answer only overwrites part of the file and does no inserting at all.

Answer (score 0):

@Jake: StringBuilder is better and easiest

```
public static void WriteToFile(string path, string text)
{
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

        stringBuilder.AppendLine("a,b,c");
        stringBuilder.Append(File.ReadAllText(path)).AppendLine();
        File.WriteAllText(path, stringBuilder.ToString()); 
}
```

**Edit:**
But StringBuilder has a buffer limit: Maximum Capacity 2147483647